# Export to Function which is called using Json is not exporting data in excel format

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, c#-4.0, export-to-excel

Hi I'm using json to call a function which calls another function which finally calls ExpotToExcel function. The functions are as following

```
$.ajax({
                type: "post",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
               // dataType: "json",
                url: "Model/Services/CurrentHistoryService.asmx/TestingExport",
                data: JSON.stringify(empno),
                success: function (resp) {
                    if (!(resp == null)) {
                        $('#ExportEmpInfo').empty();
                        $('#ExportEmpInfo').append('<p><b>' + 'Data Has been Exported to Excel successfully ' + '</b></p>');
                    }
                    else {

                        $('#ExportEmpInfo').empty();
                        $('#ExportEmpInfo').append('<p><b>' + 'Exporting to Excel Failed' + '</b></p>');

                    }


                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('TextStatus:' + textStatus + ' errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
                }
            })
```

WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public void TestingExport(string empNo)
        {
            RefEmployeeRepository emply = new RefEmployeeRepository();
            List<RefEmployee> empcurlist = emply.GetEmployeeCurrentByEMPNO(empNo);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = ToDataTable(empcurlist);
            string title = "Customer Current Information";
            ReferenceDataLogic.GenerateExcelReport(title, dt);

        }
```

GenerateExcelReport Function:

```
public static void GenerateExcelReport(string value, DataTable localTable)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();    
            DataTable dtHeader = new DataTable();
            dtHeader.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(value));
            DataTable dtBlankRow = new DataTable();
            dtBlankRow.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(" "));
            ds.Tables.Add(dtHeader);
            ds.Tables.Add(dtBlankRow);
            ds.Tables.Add(localTable);

            HelperFunctions.ExportToExcel(HttpContext.Current.Response, ds);
        }
```

ExportToExcel function:

```
 public static void ExportToExcel(HttpResponse response, DataSet ds)
        {
            try
            {
                response.Clear();
                response.ClearContent();
                response.Charset = "";
                response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

                DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();

                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
                {

                    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

                    HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

                    stringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                    htmlWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
                    dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[i];
                    dg.DataBind();
                    dg.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
                    response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
                }
                response.Flush();
                response.Close();
                response.Write("");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

The control is going through all these functions but it is not generating Excel file after going through last Export to Excel function. But if I call this function by using another code behind method directly instead of using json to call web method which call this method indirectly then I'm getting Excel sheet. Please help me with this problem why the excel sheet is not getting generated after the function is executed with out errors.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of Research I found that we can't call ExportToExcel functionality by using Json format because there will be conflict between the response that is returned and the response json is expecting.